# Fluent nHibernate Confiiguration Error

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

i m doing the configuration of Fluent nHibernate in my application with the following code ,

```
var FNHConfig = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("FNHConnection"))
                    )
                    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()))
                    .BuildConfiguration();

            return FNHConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
```

but it giving exception saying that "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. ". anyone have idea how to solve this exception ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you will have an issue with your FluentMaps somewhere rather than it being the configuration.

Comment: m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() , GetCallingAssembly is my DAL assembly , which do not have mapping define over there, should i have to define mapping in DAL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a mapping problem like Mark says above but you need to provide more detail.  That is the generic outer exception that is thrown if you fail to build the Session Factory.

```
try
{
    var FNHConfig = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("FNHConnection"))
                )
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()))
                .BuildConfiguration();

        return FNHConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Take a look at the error in the console window and you will most likely be lead to the culprit of this exception.

Comment: Inner Exception message is "'FluentNHibernate.Automapping.IAutoClasslike, FluentNHibernate, Version=1.2.0.712, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880' is missing a parameterless constructor."

Comment: Thanks, issue resolve , some references were missing that is why it was throwing exception ..

Answer (score 1):

If you dive into the inner exception it will most likely tell you what the issue is, NH3.X has pretty decent exception messages.

I'll take a stab in the dark and say that you haven't marked all the public **Properties**, **Methods** and **Events** on your object as `virtual`.

Can you post your Business Objects and Mapping Classes.

Comment: Inner Exception stated that "FluentNHibernate.Automapping.IAutoClasslike, FluentNHibernate, Version=1.2.0.712, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880' is missing a parameterless constructor."

Comment: thanks  @ issue resolve , some references were missing that is why it was throwing exception